# Adding new Blade directives (Prefix and Suffix fields?) [PhpStorm]

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-blade, phpstorm-2018.1

I am using *Windows 7*, *PhpStorm 2018.1.3* and *Laravel 5.6*. 
I have installed `spatie/laravel-permission` and I would like to add the following Blade directives in PhpStorm:

**https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-blade-directives**

For example:

```
@role('writer')
    I am not a writer...
@endrole
```

and:

```
@hasallroles($collectionOfRoles)
...
@endhasanyrole
```

So:

1. I go to: `File / Settings / Languages & Frameworks / Blade / Directives`
2. Click on  `+` (Add directive) button
3. Enter `Name`
4. check `has parameter`

... and now what? What should I enter in `Prefix` and `Suffix` fields for these particular cases (`@role('writer')` and `@hasallroles($collectionOfRoles)`)?

Comment: Why don't you look at how other directives are entered there? if you look at them you will see that IDE wants PHP code equivalent for those tags.